# json parsing a repeating variable with gson

Tags: gson

I'm trying to parse json request using google GSON (on Android although this is generic pasring question). Having trouble with creating the correct object structure to match the following JSON object.

JSON object

```
 "slideshow": [
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/www.myurl.com"
        },
        {
            "url": "http:\/\/www.myurl2.com"
        }]
```

Java Object

```
public static class Slideshow {
        //@SerializedName("url")
        private String[] slideUrl;

        public String[] getSlideUrl() {
            return slideUrl;
        }

        public void setSlideUrl(String[] slideUrl) {
            this.slideUrl = slideUrl;
        }
    }
```

Getting Parse error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: [{"url":"http://www.myurl.com"},{"url":"http://www.myurl2.com"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private List<String> slideUrl;
```

and also change the getter and setter.

Cheers
Ron